# Saving data in Windows Phone application for user settings in Windows Phone using a global class

Tags: c#, class, save, windows-phone-8.1, global

I'm a iOS developer starting to learn Windows Phone development. I have a question about saving data in a Windows Phone app like you do with `NSUserDefaults` in `iOS`.

I'm developing an app using the Windows Runtime API and **not** the Silverlight API. I've seen that Silverlight as something called `Isolated Storage` and Windows runtime API has `Application Data Storage`.

My question is if somebody with more experience in Windows Phone development and `C#` could show me and guide me on how to create a global class that I can use to store settings in my Windows Phone app.

In iOS I have a class that uses NSUserDefaults to store and retrive for example if the user is logged in or not etc. It looks like this:

```
//
//  RPStoreNSUserDefault.m
//
+ (RPStoreNSUserDefault *)sharedInstance
{
    static RPStoreNSUserDefault *shared = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        shared = [[RPStoreNSUserDefault alloc] init];
    });

    return shared;
}

- (void)storeObject:(id)object forKey:(NSString*)key
{
    NSData *serializer = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:object];

    @synchronized(self) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:serializer forKey:key];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
}

- (id)retrieveObjectForKey:(NSString*)key
{
    NSData *serializer = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:key];

    return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:serializer];
}
```

How would I do the same thing using what I understad the `Application Data Storage` in Windows Phone and c#?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a Storage service I've created for working with WinRT both on Store and Phone.

It uses James Newtons Json.net to serialize and deserialize objects to json before storing them and makes full use of generics.

You might want to look into StorageFile as well. See Jerry Nixons blogpost: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/06/windows-8-how-to-read-files-in-winrt.html

```
public class StorageService : IStorageService
{
    #region Settings

    public void SaveSetting(string key, string value)
    {
        Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        localSettings.Values[key] = value;
    }

    public void DeleteSetting(string key)
    {
        Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        localSettings.Values.Remove(key);
    }

    public string LoadSetting(string key)
    {
        Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        var value = localSettings.Values[key];

        if (value == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return value.ToString();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Objects

    public async Task<bool> PersistObjectAsync<T>(string key, T value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key) || value == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        Windows.Storage.StorageFolder localFolder =
            Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, Formatting.Indented);

        var file = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync(key, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, json);

        return true;
    }

    public async Task<T> RetrieveObjectAsync<T>(string key)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        var localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

        try
        {
            var file = await localFolder.GetFileAsync(key);
            string json = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(exp.Message);
            return default(T);
        }
    }

    public async Task<bool> DeleteObjectAsync(string key)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        Windows.Storage.StorageFolder localFolder =
            Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

        try
        {
            StorageFile file = await localFolder.GetFileAsync(key);
            await file.DeleteAsync();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(exp.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}

public interface IStorageService
{
    void SaveSetting(string key, string value);

    void DeleteSetting(string key);

    string LoadSetting(string key);

    Task<bool> PersistObjectAsync<T>(string key, T value);

    Task<T> RetrieveObjectAsync<T>(string key);

    Task<bool> DeleteObjectAsync(string key);
}
```

Comment: So I need to install Json.net via NuGet Packages? And the you name the class StorageFile and then that class implements IStorageSercive, or what is IStorageService? @Deani Hansen

Comment: Yes, you'll need the nuget package. Besides that you should be good to go. I've added the interface IStorageService to the code sample. The interface isn't strictly necessary, but it could turn out helpful when your project size increases and you need to seperate things.
Regarding storagefile, I was merely emphasizing that in order to understand what's fully going on looking at StorageFile via the blogpost could be helpful.

Comment: It work really well. Thank you for your time and explenation @Deani Hansen